# Install windows 10 beside ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, multi-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have a partition list like this:
[image]

As you can see above, the partition labeled **C** which partition is in **/dev/sda4** has a **ntfs** format, in that partition I tried to install windows 10 x64 but I couldn't because gave me this error:

> windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style

The only solution that I find is use windows CMD to execute the below comands:

1. `dispart`
2. `listdisk`
3. `select disk 0`
4. `clean`
5. `convert gpt`
6. `exit`

But I cannot do that because it seems that in the **4** and **5** step I can lost all my data

> How can I fix this to install without problems windows in that partition?

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with either of the other answers. If you convert to MBR(msdos) you break Ubuntu. And you do not have to install Windows first, although often recommended.

You issue is just that you booted the Windows installer from your UEFI boot menu in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode, not the UEFI boot mode.

Both Windows & Ubuntu install in the mode that you boot installer. And Windows only installs or boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. And only boots in BIOS mode from MBR partitioned drives.

But converting your UEFI/gpt system to BIOS/MBR is a step back to the 35 year old configuration (but then well known) from the newer UEFI/gpt configuration which now is known well enough to work for almost all systems.

Answer (score 0):

I advise against disabling Secureboot and UEFI, which is required in some suggested solutions.

When installing dual boot systems, you must install Windows(x) first, and allow windows to handle the partitioning. Windows overwrites the boot loader and does not recognise linux installations.

After Windows is fully installed and updated, then install linux second, linux installers will recognise the Windows OS on disk, and add it to the boot loader as an option.

You will need to back-up your existing linux data prior to the Windows install, and restore it post install windows and linux.

Other options which will keep your current install and data intact would be install windows to a VM using docker-machine, VMWare or Virtualbox.

Comment: On an EFI-mode installation, Windows does not overwrite existing boot loader(s), but it does set its boot loader first in the boot order. This can be changed with the standard `bcdedit` command or with the third-party GUI [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) utility. In other words, installing Windows second is quite possible, and fixing the boot order issue is done much more easily than re-installing Ubuntu.